# Having trouble parsing a response from Facebook graph

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph

I am trying to find out if the permission for 'publish_action' has been granted for a user (using php).

I can query the graph ok, I am just stuck on parsing the response to be able to get publish_actions = 'granted'.

Query is:

> $user_permissions =
>   "https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token="
>   .$access_token;
>
> $permissions = json_decode(file_get_contents($user_permissions));
>
> If I print the response
>
> print_r($permissions);

I get...

> stdClass Object ( [data] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object (
>   [permission] => installed [status] => granted ) [1] => stdClass Object
>   ( [permission] => public_profile [status] => granted ) [2] => stdClass
>   Object ( [permission] => publish_actions [status] => granted ) ) )
>
> Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted
>   to string

Basically I just want to be able to assign a variable in php if publish_actions[status] == 'granted'

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

Trying what Sahil below suggested:

```
$user_permissions = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=" .$access_token;

$permissions = json_decode(file_get_contents($user_permissions, TRUE));

$hasPublishPerm = false;
print_r($permissions['data']);
print_r($permissions);
foreach($permissions['data'] as $permission){
   if($permission['permission']=="publish_actions" && 
      $permission['status']=="granted"){
        $hasPublishPerm = true;
        break;
   }
}

if($hasPublishPerm){
   echo "User has granted the publish permission";
}
else{
   echo "User has NOT granted the publish permission";
}
```

I get this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this-

```
$hasPublishPerm = false;
foreach($permissions['data'] as $permission){
   if($permission['permission']=="publish_actions" && 
      $permission['status']=="grantedd"){
        $hasPublishPerm = true;
        break;
   }
}

if($hasPublishPerm){
   echo "User has granted the publish permission";
}
else{
   echo "User has NOT granted the publish permission";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That looks like it should work but I am getting an error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Do a `print_r($user_permissions['data'])` and `print_r($user_permissions)` just before `foreach` and tell me the result

Comment: Sorry, my mistake... here is the code I am using:

$user_permissions = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=" .$access_token;

$permissions = json_decode(file_get_contents($user_permissions));
print_r($permissions);

I get...

stdClass Object ( [data] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [permission] => installed [status] => granted ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [permission] => public_profile [status] => granted ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [permission] => publish_actions [status] => granted ) ) )
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: You are using the different variable. You using the same in for loop or the other . It shoul be `foreach($permissions['data'] as $permission){` not `foreach($user_permissions['data'] as $permission){`. If this is correct give me the response of `print_r` what will I do of the code that you have printed, I need the response.

Comment: I cant understand why are you not even able to integrate my code in yours- such a simple thing. You'll struggle big time this way, hire a technical guy instead. BtW, I've edited the answer pl check

Comment: Thankyou Sahil, I got it working with your code and a minor change to mine, appreciate your help.